# php file upload do NOT replace old one

Tags: php

I'm not good at php coding, can somebody help me with this php upload code.

I have got php file for upload file to server works perfectly but my problem is it will replace old file. I do not want replace the old one, for example if file exists upload file rename (file to file_1).

```
<?php

$target_path1 = "uploads/";
/* Add the original filename to our target path. Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {

    echo "The first file " . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) . " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " . $target_path1;
}

?>
```

i will appreciate your help...

Comment: you should **definitely** validate your user inputs. this code looks like anybody could upload a `.php`-file, execute it by accessing it via browser and by that run arbitrary commands and compromise your server.

Comment: Check if the file exists already, before uploading. Append a counter value to the file name of the new file.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
if(!file_exists("folder/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])){
       $file = "folder/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
       if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file));{
        "your message"
       }
 } else {
        $file = "your folder/01_".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file));{
         "your message"
    }
   }
```

and you can also use rand() function for rename

Answer (score 1):

Check the condition with if or while when you upload the file.
`if (file_exists("YOUR-FOLDER/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
   //code to rename your file name. Use time() or rand() etc...
  }`

Comment: thanks for your help, but unfortunately i couldn't configured with my code

Comment: Paste your full code here, so i will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check for your file using php function [isfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)

```
if (!is_file('uploads/'.$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1);
}
```

OR 
you can [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) your file name using [uniqueid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: thanks for your replay mate, I have test it your code nothing change.

Comment: it will replace the old one

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two solution for you
If you just want new file name you can add time at end of file name

```
if( isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) ){
    $tFile = $_FILES['uploaded_file'];
    $fileName=time().$tFile['name'];
    $mn_dir='your folder location'.$fileName ;
    if( !@move_uploaded_file( $tFile['tmp_name'] , $mn_dir) ){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

but if you want check the file exist

```
if( file_exists("Your Folder/".$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) ){
    // you can add number to file , I think you should add tile because file_1 and file_2 , ... may be exist

    $tFile = $_FILES['uploaded_file'];
    $fileName=time().$tFile['name'];
    $mn_dir='your folder location'.$fileName ;
    if( !@move_uploaded_file( $tFile['tmp_name'] , $mn_dir) ){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }

}else{
    // upload the file
}
```

Comment: thanks mate for your help, but i couldn't success. do i have to add all my code to else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Make a function something like

```
public function getUniqueName($path, $name) {
    $name = str_replace(" ", "_", mb_eregi_replace('\s+', ' ', $name));

    $i = 0;
    $uniqueName = $name;
    while (file_exists("{$path}/{$uniqueName}")) {
        $i++;
        $uniqueName =  $name . $i;
    }
    return $uniqueName;
}
```

And before uploading your file, go through the function to get an unique name. Hope it helps.